# Are these multiple capture moves legal in Spanish checkers?

Tags: checkers

when playing the Spanish checkers wondering if the following moves are allowed (please see picture)

[image: Spanish checkers]

if is the turn for blacks, can the crowned move like the red arrow?

1. move to E8 capture white
2. move to A4
3. move to D1 capturing white

And can the crowned whites (green arrow):

1. move to D5 capturing black
2. move to E6
3. move to G4 capturing black

Are these moves valid?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe either of those moves would be legal. While Spanish Checkers is a ["flying kings" variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts#Flying_kings;_men_cannot_capture_backwards), the constraint that each diagonal move must capture a piece still applies - hence black's move from E8 to A4 is not allowed as part of one turn, and neither is white's move from D5 to E6.

Comment: IMO, it's not conclusive. The international draughts are also present in a similar table on this page, and yet [the diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts#/media/File:Probl%C3%A8me_Jeu_de_dames_SR.gif) on the same page that is associated with international draughts shows the king changing direction mid-turn (the move "Les Blancs prennent 6 pions...") similar to what's asked in the question

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Every individual diagonal move in the turn involves a capture though, that's the difference.

Comment: You are right, I missed that.